# Boost bind callbacks linker error

Tags: c++, boost

Working on a chat I want to use callbacks as a way to "transport" messages from a particular client's stream, to a server, which should later send that message to other clients. 
Here's the code for that functionality:

```
void Server::waitForConnection(){

    Connection::pointer connect = Connection::create(accept.get_io_service());

    accept.async_accept(connect->getSocket(), boost::bind(&Server::acceptConnection, this, connect, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}


void Server::acceptConnection(Connection::pointer connection, const boost::system::error_code& error){
    if (!error)
    {
        connections.push_back(connection);
        connection->readMsg(boost::bind(&Server::msgHandler,this, boost::placeholders::_1));
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Server::acceptConnection error" << std::endl;
    }
    waitForConnection();

}
```

--

```
template<typename T> void Connection::readMsg(T msgHandler){
    const char delim = '\n';
    //boost::asio::async_read_until(soc, boost::asio::buffer(arr), delim);
    std::string tmp;
    do{
        boost::asio::read_until(soc, buf, delim);
        std::istream is(&buf);
        std::getline(is,tmp);
        msgHandler(tmp);
    } while (tmp != "leave");
}
```

Upon compilation I get the following error:

> Server.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Connection::readMsg,class std::allocator > >,class boost::_bi::list2,struct boost::arg<1> > > >(class boost::_bi::bind_t,class std::allocator > >,class boost::_bi::list2,struct boost::arg<1> > >)" (??$readMsg@V?$bind_t@XV?$mf1@XVServer@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@_mfi@boost@@V?$list2@V?$value@PAVServer@@@_bi@boost@@U?$arg@$00@3@@_bi@3@@_bi@boost@@@Connection@@QAEXV?$bind_t@XV?$mf1@XVServer@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@_mfi@boost@@V?$list2@V?$value@PAVServer@@@_bi@boost@@U?$arg@$00@3@@_bi@3@@_bi@boost@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall Server::acceptConnection(class boost::shared_ptr,class boost::system::error_code const &)" (?acceptConnection@Server@@AAEXV?$shared_ptr@VConnection@@@boost@@ABVerror_code@system@3@@Z)

This is the minimal, compilable, code I used to try and recreate the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class A;
class B;
class C;

class C{
public:
    template <typename T>void init(T t);
};

class B{
public:
template <typename T>void init(T t);
void what(string s);
};

void B::what(string s){
    cout << "in what " << s.c_str() << endl;
}

class A{
    B obj;
    int id;
public:
    void init();
    void func(string s);


};

void A::func(string s){

    cout << s.c_str() << " yes " <<id<< endl;
}
void A::init(){
    id = rand()%1024;
    obj.init(boost::bind(&A::func, this, boost::placeholders::_1));
}

template <typename T>void B::init(T t){
    //A a;
    //(a.*t)();
    C c;
    c.init(boost::bind(&B::what, this, boost::placeholders::_1));
    t("from B");
}

template <typename T>void C::init(T t){
    //A a;
    //(a.*t)();
    t("from C");
}

int main(){
    A a;
    a.init();
    a.func("main");
    system("pause");
}
```

However it fails to serve its purpose, which makes me turn to SO and ask what might actually be causing the linker error I get. 
Full code: 
[Connection.cpp](https://pastebin.com/YCmL9pNm)
[Connection.h](https://pastebin.com/dKCpseq5)
[Server.cpp](https://pastebin.com/Bcn7V297)
[Server.h](https://pastebin.com/LKJgH0S9)
[main.cpp](https://pastebin.com/GL2XJZ6G)

Comment: [This may be helpful](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl). `Server.cpp` when linked can't see the definition of `readMsg` because it doesn't include `Connection.cpp` where it is defined (and `readMsg` is a template). Either move the implementation of `readMsg` to the `Connection.h` header or clue the linker in on what template variations you'll be needing.

Comment: @Ics, what is the explicit class specifier for boost::bind in the latter case? That is, what do I write instead of `int` here: `template void foo<int>();`

Comment: Heh, you can decipher it from the error message: `class boost::_bi::bind_t<void,class boost::_mfi::mf1<void,class Server,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class boost::_bi::list2<class boost::_bi::value<class Server *>,struct boost::arg<1> > > `. Due to this, it is probably easier to just move the implementation to the header. Or you could likely use `decltype`.

Comment: @Ics, yeah, my thoughts exactly; thought there was a shortcut.
Thank you. That solved my problem.